# cross domain selenium test -- how to track the browser URL?

Tags: url, selenium, cross-domain, capybara, capture

I maintain a test suite utilizing Selenium and Capybara.  While I can convince Selenium to access pages outside of my home domain, it appears that Capybara cannot track the URL in the browser's address bar.  I tracked this deficiency down to behavior in Selenium::WebDriver, which is Ruby's binding to Selenium 2.

Googling around, it looks like Selenium has what appears to be a mode you can set it in, which enables cross-domain operation.  However, I find no reference to anything specific.

Some folks on StackOverflow talk about using either Chrome or Firefox with "elevated privileges," but again, I'm just not finding any information on using such features.  Inevitably, these questions end up unanswered.

Still other popular SO suggestsions talk about using the "open" command to explicitly bring the browser to a new site.  This isn't acceptable for the obvious reason that users don't type domain names as a general rule.  For example, if I visit, say, youtube.com, and find a video I like with a Twitter icon under the description, then clicking on that Twitter button should direct me to an appropriate twitter.com address.  The user does not have to type the twitter address manually.  Making use of selenium's open command breaks the test, because the test no longer reflects user behavior (it emulates someone actually typing an address in the bar), and thus breaks the intent of the test, which is to confirm whether or not the twitter button actually works as intended.

I'm beginning to believe that true, automated cross-domain operation is simply impossible.

So, basically, I have two questions:

(1) Given a test script which opens Selenium on, say, "www.example.com", and I ask Selenium to click on a link which directs the browser elsewhere, is it =possible= to somehow capture the URL the browser's address bar reads after the click succeeds?  And (2) Knowing that it is possible, =how= do I do it?  I'm simply not finding any information on this.  If I read @session.driver.browser.current_url, it would still report a URL on example.com, not the browser's current URL.

I'm not quite sure how to provide sample source code to help illustrate what I want in a way that wouldn't confuse the matter with irrelevant detail, but if folks want sample source code, please let me know, and I'll try to whip something up.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
selenium.click("some redirect link");
selenium.waitforpagetoload("30000"); //page load time
string url=selenium.getlocation(); //storing the url in a string.
```

If this is not Helpful,please post a **sample code** or a **link to webpage** where you are doing this test.

I don't know how to do it in Ruby. But i will post the **HTML code** for this test. So you paste this code in your **Selenium IDE** and export it as **Ruby** or **any language** you prefer.

HTML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.google.co.in/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>open</td>
<td>youtube</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>id=redirect_link</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>verifyLocation</td>
<td>resultant_page_URL</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi rannu!  Thanks for your feedback.  Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work because the API implemented in Ruby's Selenium::WebDriver seems incomplete -- it doesn't offer anything like getLocation().  However, I found what I think is a usable work-around -- I ask the web driver to evaluate "document.URL" in Javascript and return the string.  Perhaps unsurprisingly, this also returns any query string, which is actually even _more_ useful to me than the plain URL!  Thank you for your response!  It was just the kick of inspiration I needed.